# Retrive content with exec js between two HTML tags (<li class="mortadela"> </li>)

Tags: javascript, html, tags, exec

I need to retrieve all content on HTML page for this tags to an array.

For this I use this code

```
var myregexp = /(<li class="mortadela">)(+?)(<\/li>/;
var match = myregexp.exec(html_text);
```

But this don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/)), your life would be 8000+ easier:

```
var mortadelaValues = [];

$('.mortadela').each(function(){
  var content = $(this).html();

  mortadelaValues.push(content);
});

console.log(mortadelaValues);
```

Note that I'm using `$(this).html()` for the content. This allows to get any markup inside each `.mortadela`. If you just need the text, you can replace it with `$(this).text()`.

Working example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/Itexevu/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

If you cannot use those libraries, you'll need a little more work:

```
var mortadelaValues = [];
var mortadelas = document.getElementsByClassName('mortadela');
var mCount = mortadelas.length;

for( i=0; i < mCount; i++){
  var content = mortadelas[i].innerHTML;
  mortadelaValues.push(content);
}

console.log(mortadelaValues);
```

The concept is the same, but we're using native `document.getElementsByClassName` and `for`, instead of jQuery's selector and `.each()` functions. Again, if you just need the text, not the markup, you can simply swap `innerHTML` for `textContent`.

Working example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/Itexevu/2/edit?html,js,console,output).

Be warned tho that support for `document.getElementsByClassName` [is limited to newer browsers (no support for IE6-8)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname).